# How to upgrade now from Ubuntu 15.10 (end of life) to the latest OS?

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade

I missed upgrading my current Ubuntu 15.10 to the latest release. Now its end of life if I am not wrong. How to upgrade now to the latest one?

Please see the exact status of my system below:

```
ravi@ravi-Aspire-5315:~$  ubuntu-support-status
Support status summary of 'ravi-Aspire-5315':

You have 1909 packages (91.7%) supported until July 2016 (9m)
You have 16 packages (0.8%) supported until April 2017 (9m)

You have 0 packages (0.0%) that can not/no-longer be downloaded
You have 156 packages (7.5%) that are unsupported

Run with --show-unsupported, --show-supported or --show-all to see more details
ravi@ravi-Aspire-5315:~$
```

Also I didn't update my system since a long time and software updater shows 339 MB to be downloaded as security updates and other updates.

> EDIT#1

---

I followed the [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release) as provided in the comment to my question. 
1st I ran the below command to change `archive.ubuntu.com` to `old-releases.ubuntu.com`

```
sudo sed -i -re 's/([a-z]{2}\.)?archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

But when I try to update, I get the below error of `404 Not Found`

```
ravi@ravi-Aspire-5315:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily InRelease                                                              
Hit http://archive.canonical.com wily InRelease
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-updates InRelease
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-backports InRelease
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-security InRelease
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily Release.gpg
Hit http://archive.canonical.com wily/partner Sources
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-updates Release.gpg  
Hit http://archive.canonical.com wily/partner i386 Packages
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-backports Release.gpg
Hit http://archive.canonical.com wily/partner Translation-en
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-security Release.gpg
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily Release
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-updates Release
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-backports Release
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-security Release
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily/main Sources                                                                                
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily/main Translation-en_IN
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily/main Translation-en
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily/multiverse Translation-en_IN
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily/restricted Translation-en_IN
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily/universe Translation-en_IN
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily/universe Translation-en
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-updates/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-updates/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-updates/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-updates/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-updates/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-updates/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-updates/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-updates/main Translation-en_IN
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-updates/multiverse Translation-en_IN
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-updates/restricted Translation-en_IN
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-updates/universe Translation-en_IN
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-updates/universe Translation-en
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-backports/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-backports/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-backports/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-backports/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-backports/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-backports/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-backports/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-backports/main Translation-en_IN
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-backports/main Translation-en
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-backports/multiverse Translation-en_IN
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-backports/restricted Translation-en_IN
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-backports/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-backports/universe Translation-en_IN
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-backports/universe Translation-en
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-security/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-security/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-security/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-security/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-security/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-security/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-security/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]
Err http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-security/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-security/main Translation-en_IN
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-security/main Translation-en
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-security/multiverse Translation-en_IN
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-security/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-security/restricted Translation-en_IN
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-security/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-security/universe Translation-en_IN
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com wily-security/universe Translation-en
W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-updates/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-updates/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-updates/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-updates/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-backports/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-backports/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-backports/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-backports/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-backports/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-backports/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-security/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-security/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-security/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-security/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.17 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
ravi@ravi-Aspire-5315:~$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow the [instructions given in the documentation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes?_ga=1.92694106.616881589.1457510486#Upgrading_from_Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_or_15.10):

- Open the "Software & Updates" Setting in System Settings.
- Select the 3rd Tab called "Updates".
- Set the "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version" dropdown menu to "For any new version".
- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type in "update-manager" (without the quotes) into the command box.
- Software Updater should open up and tell you: New distribution release '16.04 LTS' is available.
- Click Upgrade and follow the on-screen instructions.